# Why is second Echo being displayed first in a while loop?

Tags: shell

I am testing a small script to see if i can kill multiple jobs in autosys. But the shell script is not working, somehow echo of variable displays before echo start. Does second echo run in a child program?

```
#!/bin/bash
  while IFS=read line; do
   echo "Start"
   echo "$line"
  done < "run.dat"
```

I want the output to be 
Start
Some line in run.dat
Start 
Some line in run.dat

But what i am getting is 
Some line in run.dat
Start

Please suggest.

Comment: remove IFS=, while read line ... is the correct syntax.

Comment: your code doesn't work on my machine, giving line command not found error

Comment: Check this link: http://en.kioskea.net/faq/1757-how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line

Answer (score 0):

Removing `IFS=read` is not the correct answer.

Adding a space between `IFS=` and `read` is.

That line says `while` `IFS=read` `line` (i.e. while the `line` command returns true when the `IFS` variable has the value `read` in the `line` command's environment).

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 for more information/details.